# int[] argument is not valid for method arguments T[]

Tags: java, generics, compiler-errors, integer

I am working on a sorting algorithm class and a main class to test the Sorting Algorithms. Whenever I try to call a method from the sorting algorithm class in the main class, I get an error similar to this one:

> The method quickSortRandom(T[], int) in the type SortAlgorithms is not applicable for the arguments (int[], int)

I am attempting to input an array of integers into a method that accepts Type T[], and I do not understand why that doesn't work or how to fix it. Here is the main method:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        int arr[] = {10, 7, 8, 9, 1, 5};
        int n = arr.length;
        
        SortAlgorithms s = new SortAlgorithms();
        s.quickSortRandom(arr,arr.length); }
```

And here is the quickSortRandom method in the sorting algorithms class:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>>
       void quickSortRandom(T[] array, int n)
    {
        quickSortRandom(array, 0, n-1);
    } // end quickSortRandom
```

Comment: `Integer arr[]` instead of `int arr[]`?

Comment: `int` isn't an object type, thus it can't `extends` anything, thus it can't satisfy `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`.

Answer (score 2):

The method currently accepts any array of `Comparable`s. However, unfortunately, primitives (such as `int`s) aren't comparables, and you'll need to use the wrapper class, `java.lang.Integer` instead:

```java
Integer[] arr = {10, 7, 8, 9, 1, 5};
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason, why this not works is, that `int` in Java is a primitive data type. You need a referential data typed (Something inheriting Object), for example `Integer` (the wrapper class for `int`s).
Generic Types `T` may only be references, so you must wrap you `int`s into `Integer`s, which automatically happens, as soon as you change the data Type of `int arr[]` to `Integer arr[]`.

And of course, as mentioned by Mureinik: `T` must be a `Comparable`, which `int` isn't and can't be.